# Uber API sandbox - history is empty

Tags: api, uber-api

I am testing Uber API User Activity endpoints in sandbox.
I have created a request, then successively changed its status from "processing" to "completed" - request details returns me `status: "completed"`.

However when I try to fetch history (both v1.1 & v1.2), I receive an empty "history" array: `{"count":0,"offset":0,"limit":5,"history":[]}`

Is it currently impossible to test history in the sandbox, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sandbox is meant to test the `/request` endpoint so that you can test your code without requesting a live ride. This means a fake ride is created when you make a `POST` to `/request` which you can change the status for, get a receipt or map, and cancel, as you have been able to do.

When using other endpoints like `/products` or `/history`, real data is returned, even if you are in the sandbox. The rides or set variables in sandbox do not affect this data -- i.e. your sandbox ride does not get added to `/history`, and making a product surge in sandbox does not change real estimates in `/estimates/price`.

You are receiving empty history because the user associated with the access token has not taken any real rides with Uber. The response reflects the actual history and this is the correct way to test the history endpoint.